# Checking for Package Presence in RHEL Repositories When no Access to Our Subscription is Available

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I am working in an air-gapped Linux network. Specifically, RHEL 6.9.

There are several points of context that need to be given before I ask my question:

1. We have a full, legal RHEL subscription. However, IT maintains the subscription, and I have no access to our organization's RHEL account.
2. Installed packages are managed extremely tightly by IT. There are no local repositories I have access to. I cannot install **or even check the availability of a given package** myself. Only IT may install packages.
3. Any package **that is part of the official RHEL repositories** is approved for use on our network. (But as stated above, we have to open a ticket with IT and ask them to install it.)
4. Any desired package **that is not part of the official RHEL repositories** must go through a very arduous approval process before we may open a ticket asking IT to install it.

There's a particular package I'd like to have installed. My problem is that I don't know if it is part of the official RHEL repositories. As described above, I need to know the yes / no answer to this question to know how to proceed in requesting this of IT.

Obviously, I don't want to purchase my own personal RHEL subscription just to be able to see if a given package is in the official RHEL repositories. And, for all the reasons stated above, I cannot use my company's fully-legal subscription to check.

In the past, I've asked members of our IT team (who do obviously have direct access to the RHEL repositories) to check for me if a given package is in the official RHEL repositories. However, this is growing wearisome for both them and me.

So finally, my question...

**Without an RHEL subscription that I have access to**, how can I find out the yes / no answer to this question:

> Is package X in the official RHEL 6.9 repositories?

Comment: Can you ask your IT group for a list of all packages available once every few months? Shouldn't bother them too much (coming from a former IT guy dealing with requests like these).

Additionally, CentOS aims to be as close to parity with RHEL as possible, so perhaps look for the software you need in their base repos and get an idea of it might be in the official RHEL repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a full package list for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9 on
distrowatch.com.

The link is
https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat&pkglist=true&version=rhel-6.9#pkglist.